# Castle Windsor - Register all interfaces with factory method

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a number of interfaces:

- `IFirstProvider`
- `ISecondProvider`
- `IThirdProvider`
- etc..

I'm trying to register all these interfaces so that they use a factory method to get the instance:

```
container.Register
    (  
        AllTypes
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .Where(t => t.IsInterface && t.Name.EndsWith("Provider"))
            .Configure(c => c.UsingFactoryMethod(f => f.Resolve<DictionaryAdapterFactory>().GetAdapter<object>(c.ServiceType, session))
    );
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Instead, I have to use a `for` loop to register all these interfaces:

```
List<Type> providers = new List<Type>
    (
        Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsInterface && x.Name.EndsWith("Provider"))
    );

foreach (Type provider in providers)
{
    Type temp = provider;

    container.Register
        (
            Component
                .For(temp)
                .UsingFactoryMethod(f => f.Resolve<DictionaryAdapterFactory>().GetAdapter<object>(temp, session))
        );
}
```

Is there a better way to register these interfaces besides using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no better built in way in Windsor < 3.0

As of Windsor 3, you can do it using `Types`, instead of `AllTypes`.

`AllTypes` really means *all non abstract classes*

`Types` really means *all* types.

Yes, while this does slightly suck and is counterintuitive, since `AllTypes` came first, we couldn't change its existing behavior to maintain backward compatibility.
Also to maintain sanity it is recommended to use `Classes` instead of `AllTypes`, so you'll end up registering either `Classses` for classes and `Types` for cases like this one in your question.

Comment: Well, that is freaking awesome, except now I have to go un change a bunch of stuff I changed. :)

Comment: "AllTypes came first, we couldn't change its existing behavior.." No, but you could have added `AllTypesIncludingAbstract` which would be clearer. You could also put `[Obsolete("This has been renamed to ConcreteClasses")]` on `AllTypes`, permitting the name `AllTypes` to be re-used a few years later.